# TensorFlow: how to print out all elements in a tensor

Tags: machine-learning, python, deep-learning, tensorflow, jupyter

I have a tensor that is of the size `(19,19,5,80)`. I want to print out all the elements in it but if I use `print(XXX.eval())`, most of the elements will end up as ellipsis. How can I print all of them out?

Comment: You really don't want to see it..

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you want to do is showing the full numpy array in jupyter notebook. Use the following code:

```
import numpy
numpy.set_printoptions(threshold=numpy.nan)
```

Then run your code and see the entire activation map.